# R cannot find a conda function: Error in instalation of ee_grab

Tags: python, r, conda, google-earth-engine

I follow the directions of https://github.com/JesJehle/earthEngineGrabR 
and try to install ee_grab.

However,  I always get the following message:

```
Error: Installation problem
Error: Error 1 occurred creating conda environment earthEngineGrabR"
```

It further says that earthengine-api cannot be installed (`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - earthengine-api`).

I think that R cannot find my conda.

I also managed to install earthengine-api from the terminal (https://github.com/conda-forge/earthengine-api-feedstock#installing-earthengine-api), however R still seems unable to find it and gives the same error message.

Comment: what version of R/RStudio are you using?